# React application & GraphQl server deployment problem with Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, yarnpkg, heroku-cli, prisma-graphql

I made a react application that works with a prisma - graphql server. The server is located inside the react application. I want to deploy it with Heroku (first time ever using it). When I deploy to Heroku I get this error when I run `heroku logs --tail`

```
020-06-12T14:10:04.296156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-06-12T14:10:04.332716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-12T14:10:04.335407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-12T14:10:15.424387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-12T14:10:17.947363+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-12T14:10:17.947379+00:00 app[web.1]: > business-scheduler@0.1.0 start /app
2020-06-12T14:10:17.947379+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-06-12T14:10:17.947379+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-12T14:10:20.724920+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.52.78/
2020-06-12T14:10:20.725386+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-06-12T14:10:20.725577+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-06-12T14:10:20.725681+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-06-12T14:10:20.725971+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-06-12T14:10:20.725972+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-12T14:10:20.803624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-06-12T14:10:20.835709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-12T14:27:07.241917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=appoint-scheduler.herokuapp.com request_id=4a6d7846-488a-4a57-bd76-ee5b84c197fc fwd="94.227.127.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-12T14:27:07.688859+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appoint-scheduler.herokuapp.com request_id=83928da3-bc4a-44f5-83fb-66a7c5b2611d fwd="94.227.127.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am using yarn not npm on my project does anyone know what I need to do to be able to deploy my project? 
Because my project is not running on heroku because I get this when trying to open the deployed version

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to start the react development server on heroku. Your react app should be served as a static js bundle which is generated after you run the production build cmd `npm run build`.

Have a look at https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack which is developed for this usecase only and makes it much easier.

If you're trying to deploy the whole stack ( react + prisma + graphql server )...take a look at this [**post**](https://medium.com/@nabendu82/deploying-react-nextjs-graphql-app-in-heroku-52472805d75e) which covers it in detail.

Hope this helps !